# Finding paragraphs with containing matches and extracting fields

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a xml file and i need to get the 5th word of the 1st line if the word "bad" is available between start and end characters. How do I do this by using `awk` or `sed` in **Linux.

```
start check the label 12
d44 bad
d534 good
d443 bad
d432 bad
end

start check the label 15
d534 good
d532 good
end

start check the label 17
d52 bad
d422 good
end
```

need to do

```
if (between start and end "bad" available) then print 5th character
```

expected output

```
12
17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk -v RS="" '/start.*bad.*end/{print $5}' file
12
17
```

Comment: Hey thank you, more than the iiSeymour's answer your's suits the problem i was facing.

Comment: Hey in your method also it sometimes it does not give the exact character. any clue?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KvaDJcbA i added the command i used as well in the bellow of the file

Comment: i think it's so hard to parse your file. And there is no string like `start` in your file.

Comment: yeh! i use subsubsection as the START and end as the End. so between those two functions i need to find if "Microsoft Windows Administrator Default Password Detection" available and if so print the ip address. its easy if u can paste it on gedit file i guess

Answer (score 3):

Simply with `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk '/bad/{print $5}' RS='end' file
12
17
```

Comment: hey.... thank you very much. but then again, i have a small issue. when i apply that to certain files. the 1st output gives the character 6 and the rest is correctly giving 5th character. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sed command

```
sed -r ':loop;N;/(\n$|end$)/{s/([^0-9]+) ([0-9]+) .*bad.*/\2/gp;d;b};s/\n/ /g;t loop' file
```

Comment: Thnx will try this as well :)